# Label tag for text input element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

I'm adding a form element like so:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'product_name', array(
    'label' => 'product name',
    '... )
);
```

I'd like to reference the `product_name` label in the `ViewScript` decorator script as I'm doing it with `product_name` text input `<?php echo $this->form->product_name; ?>` but the label tag rendered by the "addElement" have no "name" attribute. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Use [Zend manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.decorators.html) and check out the section ["Rendering Individual decorators"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.decorators.html#zend.form.decorators.individual) to see how to render your label alone.

**Option 2:** You can skip the label part, remove its decorator in the form code as follows, and then add it in the form's view script directly with styles you want to add:

```
  $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('product_name');
  $element->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
          ->removeDecorator('Label');
```

Then, in the view script:

```
  <span class="label"> Product Name: </span> <?php echo $this->form->product_name; ?>
```